# What mechanisms can make a site start gathering cookies for 3rd parties?

Tags: cookies

Imagine starting with a basic site which has no links and no code which stores tracking cookies. Assume the site should remain that way as it grows in features and content.

What are the mechanisms which could result in 3rd parties to implicitly starting to gather cookies (to track visitors of my site).

`Implicitly` means something like:

> I thought I was adding a youtube link to my blog and instead now google tracks people who visit my site. My site now needs to have a cookie consent banner.

Example I discovered so far:

- Putting an iframe link to youtube
- Fetching an executing JavaScript code from an external link while introducing a dropdown menu code

Comment: As soon as you embed content out of your control you also loose most control about tracking. This is especially true if you embed third party script directly into your site. And note that there are lots of other ways apart from cookies which allow tracking, thus just focusing on tracking cookies might not be enough.

Comment: This version is much clearer. Thanks.